Proof for Asymptotic Normality for MLE with Multiple Parameters
I have a question about how I can prove asymptotic properties of multiple MLE estimators. Most resources you find online give the proof for the case, where only one parameter is estimated (e.g. here: https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/11/28/asymptotic-normality-mle/). In this proof, the mean-value theorem in terms of the parameter is applied to the first derivative of the likelihood to obtain an expression like $(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) = - \frac{L_n'(\theta_0)}{L_n''(\tilde{\theta})}$ and then apply asymptotic results on the likelihood. My problem with extending this kind of proof for the multiple-parameter case is that the mean-value theorem only holds for scalar functions. For vector values functions, only a inequality holds, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions.
Can somebody give me an idea how to prove asymptotic normality for multiple parameters? A reference is also appreciated of course.

There's a proof of that in Lehmann and Casella's "Theory of Point Estimation". Just mentioning that in case you can manage to get that book.

Luckily I have access, can you please tell me where I can find the proof in the book?

If it is the second edition (1998), then it is on page 463. It is Theorem 5.1 of chapter 6. The strange thing is that they name it Theorem 5.1 instead of 6.5.1. That way, there are multiple Theorem 5.1s in the entire book but you have to look specifically the Theorem 5.1 of chapter 6, which is titled "Asymptotic Optimality."

I see, thank you!

I will give a sketch of the proof, as I do not have access to the reference pointed out in the comments. Before that, note that indeed, the (mis)use of the mean value theorem/Taylor series approximation in statistics was discussed in a journal article that may be of interest to you. You may also be interested in the treatment of M-estimators (or extremum estimators), in e.g. Asymptotic Statistics by Aad van der Vaart, as MLEs turn out to be a special case.
You are right that for vector-valued functions, no such thing as a MVT exists (the journal article I linked gives counterexamples and such). The closest you can get is the following: let $f$ be a vector valued function say $f:
\mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$. Then applying the mean value theorem element-wise to each function output $f_{i}$, $i = 1, 2, \dots, q$, we obtain
$$
f(b) - f(a) = \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla f_{1}(c_{1})\\
\nabla f_{2}(c_{2})\\
\vdots\\
\nabla f_{q}(c_{q})
\end{bmatrix}(b-a)
$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and each of the $c_{i}$ is on the line between $a$ and $b$. I denote as $\nabla  f_{i}$ the gradient ($p$-dimensional row vector) of $f_{i}$ w.r.t. the $p$-dimensional input.
Now let $\ell(\theta)$ denote
$$
\ell_{n}(\theta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(f(X_{i})\mid\theta),
$$
i.e. it is the log-likelihood of an i.i.d. sample $X_{i}$ of size $n$ where each observation has density $f(\cdot\mid\theta)$ for some parameter vector $\theta$, and denote with $\frac{\partial \ell_n(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ the gradient (here column vector) of the log-likelihood w.r.t. $\theta$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} \ell_{n}(\theta)}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^T}$ the hessian matrix of the log-likelihood, both evaluated at some point $\theta$. Furthermore, let $\hat{\theta}_{n}$ denote the MLE estimate of the parameter $\theta$, $\theta_{0}$ the true value and $\theta^{\dagger}$ some value between $\hat{\theta}$ and $\theta_{0}.$ Then by the result above applied to $f = \partial \ell_{n}/ \partial \theta$ in the points $b = \hat{\theta}, a = \theta_{0}$ (the MLE and true parameter), we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial \ell_{n}(\hat{\theta})}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial \ell_{n}(\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial^{2} \ell_{n}(\theta^{\dagger})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_{0}).
$$
This is shorthand notation, but you should interpret the above as $\theta^{\dagger}$ differing for each row of the Hessian matrix (as in the general result using $f$, otherwise the above is in general not true. Under regularity conditions, the LHS is zero by the first-order conditions of the MLE maximisation problem. Multiplying by $\sqrt{n}$ and solving for $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0})$ yields
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0}) = -\left(\frac{\partial^{2} \ell_{n}(\theta^{\dagger})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}\right)^{-1} \sqrt{n}\frac{\partial \ell_{n}(\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta}
$$
The rest would be like the univariate case that you linked. The score has mean 0, and hence we have by the CLT that as $n\to\infty$
$$
\sqrt{n}\frac{\partial \ell_{n}(\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta}\overset{d}{\to} N\left(0, \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\log f(X_{1}\mid\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta}\frac{\log f(X_{1}\mid\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta^{T}}\right]\right).
$$
Similarly you can argue by the law of large numbers and the fact that $\theta^{\dagger} \overset{p}{\to} \theta_{0}$ (for each of the $q$ versions of $\theta^{\dagger}$) if you have established that the MLE is consistent, i.e. $\hat{\theta} \overset{p}{\to} \theta_{0}$.
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} \ell_{n}(\theta^{\dagger})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}\overset{p}{\to} \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\log f(X_{1}\mid \theta_{0})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}\right]
$$
If we can apply the information equality
$$
-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\log f(X_{1} \mid \theta_{0})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\log f(X_{1}\mid\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta}\frac{\log f(X_{1}\mid\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta^{T}}\right],
$$
then by continuous mapping theorem/Slutzky's theorem you get the usual result that
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_{0}) \overset{d}{\to} N\left(0,-\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}\log f(X_{1}\mid\theta_{0})}{\partial \theta \, \partial \theta^{T}}\right]\right)^{-1}\right),
$$
where in particular the variance above is the inverse of the Fisher information matrix.

Thank you very much! So the trick essentially is to apply the MVT componentwise? What would you think happens if the number of parameters goes to infinity? My intuition tells me that this proof would still work, right? (Of course I dont expect a perfect answer to this question, it is more about intuition or me missing something :D)

I don't have a good answer to this, but my guess is that it does not work. As far as I understand, you would then move to the class of semiparametric or nonparametric models, for which things are generally much more complicated.

Sometimes I wonder whether I am the only one who thinks $f(X_1\mid\theta_0)$ is far easier on the eyes than $f(X_1|\theta_0).$ I have taken the liberty of changing that, but what inspired me to edit was that I thought $“,\vdots,”$ belonged where $“,\cdots,”$ appeared. And I changed $\dfrac\cdots{\partial\theta\partial\theta^T}$ to $\dfrac\cdots{\partial\theta , \partial\theta^T},$ which is considered standard usage.

You aren't alone @MichaelHardy.
